Find expression if other expression is in string
expression1 = r'\d+e\d+e' #e.g '10e2e' or '30e4e'
expression2 = r'\d+%/\d+%' #e.g '30%/1%' or '1%/2%

For a given string, I want to extract expression1 only if expression2 is present in the string.
Example:
string1 = '30e4e 1%/2%' ->  re.search(correctRegex, string1, re.X).group(0) #should return '30e4e'
string2 = '30e4e blabla' -> re.search(correctRegex, string2, re.X) #should be None
string3 = '1%/2% 30e4e ' ->  re.search(correctRegex, string1, re.X).group(0) #should return '30e4e'

I've tried re.search(r'^(?=.*\d%/\d+%).*?(\d+e\d+e)', '1%/2% 10e2e').group(0) but it returns 1%/2% 10e2e, I want .group(0) to return only the expression I am looking for.

Step 1. Filter strings by expression2 presence. Step 2. Extract expression1

As usual, for a single match: ^(?=.*\d%/\d+%).*?(\d+e\d+e)

@WiktorStribiżew yes it works, but then re.search(r'^(?=.*\d%/\d+%).*?(\d+e\d+e)', '1%/2% 10e2e', re.X) returns 1%/2% 10e2e as match, I would like it to return 1%/2% as match.

Your question mentioned findall. The behaviour of findall and search are different.

i have edited it, sorry about this.

But now you just removed it. It is good to show your attempts and explain what the problem is with them. Now there is nothing like that in your question, and that is frowned upon. Since apparently you want to use search (and possibly also findall), it would be good to mention that in the question, and not just in the comment section.

I actually don't want to use findall, that was an oversight on my side, sorry again about it.

Please show what is holding you back to do this. What was your attempt?

My regex works as expected. You just need to extract Group 1 value.

I hope my question is clear now.

Now, it is impossible with re. You will need to use PyPi regex module and use import regex as re and then re.search(r'\d+e\d+e(?=.*\d%/\d+%)|(?<=\d%/\d+%)\d+e\d+e', text).

@AdamElKaroui What's not good with group(1)? You could modify the recommended pattern and attach | (or empty pos) to get None if no match like in this demo if that's the problem...

Regex
(?=.*\d+%/\d+%).*?(\d+e\d+e)

The lookahead (?=.*\d+%/\d+%) allows to check for the expression2.
.*? is for matching the expression1 even if there is shifted from the start of the expression2. And it's non-greedy ? allow to get more then only 1 digit for the first number \d+.
Code for testing

import re

# Strings
string1 = '30e4e 1%/2%'
string2 = '30e4e blabla'
string3 = '1%/2% 30e4e'

# Define the regex pattern
pattern = r'(?=.*\d+%/\d+%).*?(\d+e\d+e)'

# Apply the regex to each string
match1 = re.search(pattern, string1)
match2 = re.search(pattern, string2)
match3 = re.search(pattern, string3)

# Display the capture group only if there is a match (to avoid execution error)
if match1:
    print(f"Match 1: {match1.group(1)}")
if match2:
    print(f"Match 2: {match2.group(1)}")
if match3:
    print(f"Match 3: {match3.group(1)}")

Result
Match 1: 30e4e
Match 3: 30e4e

